Hashicorp Vault failing with unexpected token character in JSON error
I'm trying to use the vault-action@v2 to retrieve some secrets, but it's failing throwing the following error:
Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Here is how the actions is set:
  - name: Import secrets
    id: import-secrets
    uses: actions/vault-action@v2
    with:
      url: https://vault.gwd.net
      token: ${{ secrets.VAULT_TOKEN }}
      secrets: |
          secret/groups/SDE/github_secrets DOCKER_REPO_USER ;
          secret/groups/SDE/github_secrets DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD

The VAULT_TOKEN secret is a string and doesn't contain the < character, in fact, there is no JSON value in any of those secrets, so from where that error comes from?

Potentially a connection error to Vault, with an HTML response instead of JSON?

If that is the entire logging for the action then that is not super great. Is there any relevant logging around the error message?

This error most likely indicates that Vault did not return a valid JSON in its API response. It most likely returned HTML. This would explain '<' in position 0. Normally, Vault would return an error JSON. In this case, the request most likely did not reach Vault and was blocked prior.
The reason for this is most likely an error in the Vault URL or auth token that were blocked by an auth proxy or similar. Are you missing port 8200? The examples use this url:
url: https://vault-enterprise.mycompany.com:8200

Try invoking the endpoint yourself using curl or some other REST tool. Use this doc for reference.

Thanks, I really missed specifying the port, but now I'm getting this timeout error:
curl: (28) Failed to connect to vault-br-sbo.gwd.broadcom.net port 8200 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server.  Can I use another port if that is blocked?

You also changed your host from vault.gwd.net  to vault-br-sbo.gwd.broadcom.net. Is that intentional? I can not tell what port to use for this internal host. The scheme is https, so perhaps default port is fine. However, you may need a path in the URL. You need to get some info on this service. If it is your locally hosted service, you can look on the ingress or other configuration.
